# ImportError: No module named recsys.algorithm

Tags: python, module, terminal, importerror

I'm trying to run the first code ("Movielens") in this site http://ocelma.net/software/python-recsys/build/html/examples.html with the command (being in the same folder of ratings.dat):

```
python movielens.py ratings.dat 80
```

but i don't understand why when i run it i receive this message in the terminal:

```
  File "movielens.py", line 4, in <module>
    import recsys.algorithm
ImportError: No module named recsys.algorithm
```

Comment: `https://github.com/ocelma/python-recsys` is installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install / clone recsys library:
https://github.com/ocelma/python-recsys